# How to make this manual and automatic?

Tags: javascript

I have this code, and it basically changes the text and image on the user's screen. I would like to do this manually with the click event. but I can't, can anyone help me? please

```
let i = 0;
let img = 0;
let images = [
  '...',
  '...',
  '...',
  '...',
  '...',
  '...'
];

let textArrayImg = [
  "Moda",
  "Beleza",
  "Comportamento",
  "Decoração",
  "Entretenimento",
  "Bem-Estar"
];


let textImg = document.querySelector('.textImg');
let btnPrev = document.querySelector('.btnPrev');
let btnNext = document.querySelector('.btnNext');



function changeImg(){
  document.querySelector('.slide').src = images[img];
  textImg.textContent = textArrayImg[i];

  if(img < textArrayImg.length - 1){
    img++;
  }else {
    img = 0;
  }

  if(i < images.length - 1){
    i++;
  }else {
    i = 0;
  }

  setTimeout(changeImg, 3000);
}

changeImg();



btnPrev.addEventListener('click', () => {

});

btnNext.addEventListener('click', () => {

});
```

I already tried some ways but I would like to do it this way because it makes it easier for me

Comment: So you are just wanting to be shown how to create a click event?

Comment: @Spangle I do not know if I understood what you said, but I wanted it to continue automatically, but had two functions one to return the image and another advance, manually.

Comment: @Icepickle don't I'm sorry

Comment: I just need help to make this :(

Comment: So what do you want clicking the buttons to do? Should the button start the images changing automatically or should the images be changing automatically from the beginning?

Comment: @PaulRooney images should continue automatically from the beginning, and clicking the buttons changes, rewinds or forwards

Comment: ok then for the next button, you just need to increment the image index `img` by 1 (take care to wrap around to 0 if you reach the end of the array) and set the new image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets have a look at this code, it's basically calling itself every three seconds and automaticaly increases the count of `img`, after 3 seconds

```
function changeImg(){
  document.querySelector('.slide').src = images[img];
  textImg.textContent = textArrayImg[i];

  if(img < textArrayImg.length - 1){
    img++;
  }else {
    img = 0;
  }

  if(i < images.length - 1){
    i++;
  }else {
    i = 0;
  }

  setTimeout(changeImg, 3000);
}
```

Now this is kinda your problem as it doesn't really define how it should change, so you could add a variable to it, that indicates how it needs to change the `img` count like

```
function changeImg( inc )
```

And then change where `img` is being changed, to add `inc` to it

Now if you go with your previous button, it might have the problem that it goes below 0, so, you have to now handle that case as well, say

```
img += inc;
if (img >= textArrayImg.length) {
  img = 0;
} else if (img < 0) {
  img = textArrayImg.length - 1;
}
```

But, you still have to handle the automatic recall event for changeImg (you don't want to call it twice) in short timespan, so we should probably reset the timer when we manually change something

```
if (timer) {
  clearTimeout( timer );
}
timer = setTimeout( changeImg, 3000 ); // don't forget to declare timer where you have img and stuff
```

However, now we kinda miss the parameter in the changeImg, and we probably don't want this to automatically recall with -1 or the manual +1, so change it like

```
setTimeout( function() { changeImg( 1 ) }, 3000 );
```

and make sure your initial call then also changes it to

```
changeImg( 1 );
```

which is outside the function

Your eventhandlers can now use this function

```
btnPrev.addEventListener('click', () => {
  changeImg( -1 );
});

btnNext.addEventListener('click', () => {
  changeImg( 1 );
});
```

Note that in your `changeImg` you have no need for both `img` and `i` as a counter (I am assuming they are somewhat connected to eachother, so that they have to refer to the same index?)

So in the end, I guess you would have this

```
// at the declaration part
let timer;

// changes to the function
function changeImg( inc ){
  img+=inc;
  if (img < 0) {
    img = textArrayImg.length - 1;
  } else if (img >= textArrayImg.length) {
    img = 0;
  }
  document.querySelector('.slide').src = images[img];
  textImg.textContent = textArrayImg[img];
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout( timer );
  }
  timer = setTimeout(() => changeImg(1), 3000);
}

// initial call
changeImg(0); // keep it as 0 to start with so it automatically sets the initial items there
```

Comment: Could you publish the full code?  I'm making a mess please

Comment: @Reypic you mean the change required for the `changeImg` function?

Comment: yes this, I stay making trash :(

Comment: @Reypic I updated the things I think are relevant at the bottom :) I thought my walkthrough would have been enough though :)

Comment: thank you so much!!!! I'm beginner rsrs